# Customize output of entity Field Type

Tags: symfony

I have a form to select users widh checkboxes.

Now, the list of users is displayed in the form but only the username is displayed. I would like to display all user data with each checkboxes: name, first name, email ...

How can I do this ?

```
 $builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
'choice_label' => 'username',
'expanded' => true,
'multiple' => true,
));
```

Comment: you can do this by using http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo  Hi

I'd like to do something like this http://chmielot.blogspot.ch/2013/02/symfony2-customize-output-of-expanded.html  but I did not understand what is those 2 lignes and where put them

`$options = $citySelectionForm->get('cities')->getConfig()->getOptions();
$choices = $options['choice_list']->getChoices();`

Comment: possible, you have to use this variables in controller. `$citySelectionForm` is your `FormType`, `$choices` - array which you can pass to view renderer.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new method in the entity **User**. Something like:

```
public function getAllUserData(){
   return $this->name .' | '. $this->email (As you want);
}
```

In the form:

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
 'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
 'choice_label' => 'allUserData',
 'expanded' => true,
 'multiple' => true,
));
```

Cheers...

Comment: I'd like to do something like this http://chmielot.blogspot.ch/2013/02/symfony2-customize-output-of-expanded.html  but I did not understand what is those 2 lignes and where put them

`$options = $citySelectionForm->get('cities')->getConfig()->getOptions();
$choices = $options['choice_list']->getChoices();`